# Emacs, quick-jump and go-mode: point not updated during navigation

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to combine the go-mode `godef-jump` with quick-jump, such that I drop a marker both before and after the jump.

```
(defun my-go-quick-jump-push-def-hook (pnt)
  (interactive "d")
  (message "%s %d" (buffer-name) pnt)
  (quick-jump-push-marker)
  (godef-jump pnt)
  (quick-jump-push-marker)
  (message "%s %d" (buffer-name) (point))
)

(defun my-go-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-.") 'my-go-quick-jump-push-def-hook)
)
```

However, the `message` calls indicate that the buffer has not been updated after the call to `godef-jump` completes, and nor does `(point)` give a different value from `pnt`. But `godef-jump` does complete and does change the buffer where necessary. So something's up with the evaluation order that I can't figure out - it's almost like the actual navigation is going on lazily. Is this expected or is this something odd that go-mode is doing?

go-mode is at https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el/blob/master/go-mode.el,
quick-jump is at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/quick-jump.el

Many thanks.

Update: this problem seems to only happen when the jump is to a different buffer. I don't know enough about `with-current-buffer` (used in `godef--find-file-line-column`) to understand what's going wrong - my reading of the docs is that `with-current-buffer` shouldn't cause that buffer to be activated at all once the body completes, so I'm at a loss to understand why `godef-jump` works at all...

Comment: You may want to consider migration to [Emacs.SE](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Argh, I had no idea that even existed. Is it a matter of deleting this one and posting a new one over there? - I can't see a way to migrate this question though I may be being blind...

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, basically, see the PR I made, and the discussion: https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el/pull/85

The problem was specific to go-mode, and has now been fixed there.